# How to enable syntax highlighting for Java in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, syntax

I installed Visual Studio Code using the Java installer from Microsoft's website. 
I am able to run and debug files. I also get red underline for errors, however syntax highlighting does not work. Text is white.

I set language mode to Java and I have all required extensions installed. Is there a way to enable syntax highlighting in VS Code for Java files?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to uninstall Visual Studio Code using the provided uninstalled and than delete folder `Code` in AppData folder (Windows 10).

Than I reinstalled VS Code and syntax works just fine.